# DefaultModelBinder not binding model (always null) even though ModelState contains all required values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, defaultmodelbinder, value-provider

I am working with the sample ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I am working on a proof of concept for an API for a project I'm working on, by sending log in requests using `HttpWebRequest`s. I am submitting data as JSON and am using the Content Type "application/json".

Here is the method I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[Api]
public bool ApiLogOn(LogOnModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model != null)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problem is that even though `ModelState` contains all the keys and values that I expect to see (e.g. Dictionary contains { "UserName"="username", "Password"="password", "RememberMe"=true } which are the three properties of the LogOnModel class), the object `model` is null every time I call the method.

I do not have this problem when using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I have also tried **with** and **without** adding

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

to my `Application_Start` method.

Here is the code I am using to send requests to the method above:

```
var credentials = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "username", Password = "password", RememberMe = true };
var result = PostData<LogOnModel, bool>(@"url goes here", credentials);

protected R PostData<T, R>(string uri, T postData)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", X_REQUESTED_WITH_HEADER);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    var serializerT = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    var serializerR = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(R));

    if (postData != null)
    {
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            serializerT.WriteObject(stream, postData);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var result = (R)serializerR.ReadObject(stream);
                return result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return default(R);
        }
    } catch { return default(R); }
 }
```

Comment: What's the `[Api]` attribute that you have used? That's not standard. Is it some custom action filter you wrote? I have just tested your code without this attribute and it worked perfectly fine. Also why are you returning a boolean from an ASP.NET MVC controller action? They should return ActionResults. In your case that would be a JsonResult.

Comment: Interesting. It does seem that removing the Api Attribute does, in fact, solve the problem. It comes from http://mvcapi.codeplex.com/. I'll post this as the accepted answer for now, but I'm going to look at why that attribute causes problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that removing the [Api] Attribute solved my problem. If anyone is interested, it came from this url: http://mvcapi.codeplex.com/

The point was such that we could use methods that had both Views (for our web page) and JSON results (for our API calls). If anyone has any other ideas for this (aside from the obvious if-this-return-view-else-return-json) please feel free to comment below, I'd like to hear them.